# How to add lines between each row in Minewsweeper, Python

Tags: python, game-development

I am a student in Australia studying Digitronics, and I am unsure how to get the lines in between each row. (I can do it with the columns, but not the rows)

I have also identified several other problems, such as 
1. The player can cheat the countdown timer,
by entering the same safe co-ordinates in again and again.
2. The game crashes if the player inputs a number outside of the
board range
3. There is also the slight problem that I cannot flag any
bombs, as the function required to do that is way
beyond my comprehension, and although I am certain
I could do it in more time (i.e., several months),
the code won't allow it and I have to stop here
4. There is also the slight complication that you don't
get in the minesweeper games on Windows, and that
is the fact that you get die on the first turn. It is
impossible to do that with the regular game.

Thanks in advance

**Is there any way I can add a flagging feature, or a way to reveal the board once lost?**

```
# Matthew
# Simple Minesweeper - but not so simple anymore
# Version 3.0
# 20/9/17 - 25/10/17

from random import randint      # so there is a random mine placement
import time     # so I can delay the game
import sys      # so I can quit the game at any time`enter code here`

# Starts the loop for the game
play = True
while play == True:

    ##############################
    #### Functions Start Here ####
    ##############################

    # opens the board for use
    board = [] 

    # opens the mines list, currently empty so it can be altered later. 
    mines = []

    # determines the rows on the board
    board_row = 0

    # determines the adjacent mines
    adj = 0

    # sets a variable to be used later in the check_ans() function
    wrong = 0

    #determines the amount of rows on the board
    while True:
        board_row = int(input("For a square board, how many rows and columns? (5 min, 10 max):"))
        if board_row > 10:
            print("That is too high. Please enter another!")
        elif board_row < 5:
            print("That is too small. Please enter another!")
        else:
            break

    # adds mines for a larger board
    if board_row >= 8:
        for i in range(15):
            mines.append([randint(0,board_row-1), randint(0, board_row-1)])

    # adds smaller mines for a smaller board
    elif board_row >= 5:
        for i in range(10):
            mines.append([randint(0,board_row-1), randint(0, board_row-1)])

    # creates rows
    for i in range(board_row):
        board.append(["x"] * board_row)

    # creates the rows
    def draw_board(board):
        for i in board:
            print("|".join(i))

    # check the answers
    def check_ans():
        if row >= board_row or col >= board_row:
            print("That number is too high. The order goes 0 to ", board_row)
            wrong = 1
        else:
            wrong = 0      

    # defines the adjacent mines, by checking each of the surrounding squares, one
    # by one
    def adj_mines(r, c, adj):
        adj = 0
        if [r+1, c] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r+1, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r+1, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c+1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c] in mines:
            adj += 1
        if [r-1, c-1] in mines:
            adj += 1
        return adj

    def Intro_to_game():
        print('Hello. This is a game of Minesweeper - with a twist!')
        print('You cannot flag any bombs, because I can\'t figure out how to do that...')
        print('On each turn, select the row or column that you wish to ')
        print('disarm, and this program will do it. To let you know how')
        print('many tiles you have left to disarm, there will be a ')
        print('countdown before each turn. Enjoy, and good luck!')

    # defines number of moves required to beat the game, as
    # there is no flagging function. 
    moves = (((board_row) * (board_row) - int(len(mines))))


    ##################################
    #### Main Program Starts Here ####
    ##################################

    draw_board(board)

    # This uses a function to determine how many cells are left to
    # clear the board, as there is no way to flag. This makes the
    # game significantly harder, as you have to keep track in your
    # head of where the bombs are. 
    Intro_to_game()
    while True:
        print('===================================')
        print("Cells to clear: " + str(moves))

        # This part enters in the rows and columns. However, although
        # the lists typically start at 0, the program has to subtract
        # one from the different imputs to put them in the right place

        row = (int(input("Row: ")) - 1)

        # This part doesn't allow the player to enter
        # a number that is higher than the board range
        while row >= board_row + 1:
            print('That is not in the board range')
            row = (int(input("Row: ")) -1) 

        col = (int(input("Col: ")) - 1)

        # This part doesn't allow the player to enter
        # a number that is higher than the board range

        while col >= board_row + 1:
            print('That is not in the board range')
            col = (int(input("Col: ")) -1)              

        # checks to see if there is a bomb in the called field, if not,
        # then it repeats. If there is a bomb, it shows, "Sorry, but you
        # have blown up." Then it asks if they player would like to play
        # again. 
        check_ans()

        if wrong != 1:
            if [row, col] in mines:
                break

            else:
                board[row][col] = str(adj_mines(row,col,0))
                moves = moves - 1
        draw_board(board)
        if moves == 0:
            print("You have won!")
            time.sleep(2)
            sys.exit

    print("Sorry, but you have blown up :(")

    # draws the board again each time. 
    draw_board(board)

    # Although unconventional, this little bit processes the
    # request to play again. If yes, it breaks the loop, and
    # goes back to the start. If no, sys.exit quits the game

    print("Would you like to play again? (Yes or No)(Needs Capitals)")
    play_again = input()
    if play_again == 'Yes':
        continue
    if play_again == 'Y':
        continue
    if play_again == 'yes':
        continue
    if play_again == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add lines between each row?

Currently, say `board_row` is `5`, then your representation is

```
2|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x
```

You can add the following line to add horizontal rows.

```
print("|".join(i))
print("-" * (board_row*2-1)) # add this line
```

The board representation becomes

```
x|x|x|x|x
---------
x|x|x|x|x
---------
x|x|x|x|x
---------
x|x|x|x|x
---------
x|x|x|x|x
---------
```